# Force compilation error with sealed classes

Tags: kotlin

With sealed classes you can use exhaustive `when` expressions and omit the `else` clause when the expression returns a result:

```
sealed class SealedClass {
  class First : SealedClass()
  class Second : SealedClass()
}

fun test(sealedClass: SealedClass) : String =
    when (sealedClass) {
      is SealedClass.First -> "First"
      is SealedClass.Second -> "Second"
    }
```

Now if I were to add a `Third` to `SealedClass`, the compiler will complain that the `when` expression in `test()` is not exhaustive, and I need to add a clause for `Third` or `else`.

I am wondering however if this check can also be enforced when `test()` does not return anything:

```
fun test(sealedClass: SealedClass) {
    when (sealedClass) {
      is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
      is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

This snippet does not break if `Third` is added.
I can add a `return` statement before `when`, but this could easily be forgotten and may break if the return type of one of the clauses is not `Unit`.

How can I make sure I don't forget to add a branch to my `when` clauses?

Comment: I asked the same question in Slack a long time ago, and AFAIR, there is no solution other than making it an expression returning something. But IntelliJ should emit a warning if you forget a clause, though (my question was for an enum, not a sealed class, but it should be the same).

Comment: Hmm, yes. I have noticed I can make it return `Any?`, and force a return value, but it still feels a bit hacky.

Comment: My preferred is the run block. It's readable, doesn't change the return type of the function from Unit to Any?, and isn't more or less forgettable than adding a return or an Any? return type.

Comment: Hmm, true. Hower I am looking to be safe for the client's sake. The client can still forget to use `run`. I have expanded the question a little with an example.

Comment: Isn't worrying about a client is a little bit too much? He/she can always skip checking branches if wants to

Comment: Yes they can, but if they do that, they _explicitely_ opt out. Forgetting is a whole other thing than opting out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In inspiration by Voddan's answer, you can build a property called `safe` you can use:

```
val Any?.safe get() = Unit
```

To use:

```
when (sealedClass) {
    is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
    is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
}.safe
```

I think it provides a clearer message than just appending `.let{}` or assigning the result to a value.

---

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12380) on the Kotlin tracker which considers to support 'sealed whens'.

Comment: The downside of this is that it pollutes autocomplete as this extension method will show up on every statement.

Comment: @Tunga replace Any? with Unit? and it will not pollute as much

Answer (score 27):

The way to enforce exhaustive `when` is to make it an expression by using its value:

```
sealed class SealedClass {
    class First : SealedClass()
    class Second : SealedClass()
    class Third : SealedClass()
}

fun test(sealedClass: SealedClass) {
    val x = when (sealedClass) {
        is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
        is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
    }  // ERROR here

    // or

    when (sealedClass) {
        is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
        is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
    }.let {}  // ERROR here
}
```

Comment: If you don't actually need the return value, I find it good practise to use a dedicated 'throwaway' variable name to indicate that you're only using it to enforce an exhaustive `when`. This way you give it semantic meaning, for example: `val exhaustive = when(...)`

Answer (score 27):

Our approach avoids to have the function everywhere when auto-completing. 
With this solution you also have the when return type in compile time so you can continue using functions of the when return type.

```
Do exhaustive when (sealedClass) {
  is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
  is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
}
```

You can define this object like so:

```
object Do {
    inline infix fun<reified T> exhaustive(any: T?) = any
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: To make it less verbose you can override unary operator:
[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703263/6528121)

Answer (score 11):

We can create an extension property on type T with a name that helps explain the purpose

```
val <T> T.exhaustive: T
    get() = this
```

and then use it anywhere like

```
when (sealedClass) {
        is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
        is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
    }.exhaustive
```

It is readable, shows exactly what it does an will show an error if all cases are not covered.
[Read more here](https://proandroiddev.com/til-when-is-when-exhaustive-31d69f630a8b)

Comment: The form `val Any?.exhaustive get() = Unit` has a return value of `Unit`, just like the original non-expression `when`. If the `when` is used in an expression, the `exhaustive` extension is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

A [discussion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12380#focus=streamItem-27-4017839.0-0) triggered me to look for a more general solution and found one, for Gradle builds. **It doesn't require changing the source code!** The drawback is that compilation may become noisy.

#### `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    val taskOutput = StringBuilder()
    logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
    logging.addStandardOutputListener { taskOutput.append(it) }
    doLast {
        fun CharSequence.hasInfoWithError(): Boolean =
            "'when' expression on sealed classes is recommended to be exhaustive" in this
        if (taskOutput.hasInfoWithError()) {
            throw Exception("kotlinc infos considered as errors found, see compiler output for details.")
        }
    }
}
```

#### `build.gradle`

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    def taskOutput = new StringBuilder()
    logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
    logging.addStandardOutputListener(new StandardOutputListener() {
        void onOutput(CharSequence text) { taskOutput.append(text) }
    })
    doLast {
        def hasInfoWithError = { CharSequence output ->
            output.contains("'when' expression on sealed classes is recommended to be exhaustive")
        }
        if (hasInfoWithError(taskOutput)) {
            throw new Exception("kotlinc infos considered as errors found, see compiler output for details.")
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Change implementation of `hasInfoWithError` to generalize to other `i:`s.
- Put this code in `subprojects { }` or `allprojects { }` to apply project-wide.

References:

- Issue tracking making missing sealed case as warning:
  (which together with `kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors` would solve the issue)
  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37651
- Discussion triggering this solution:
  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12380#focus=streamItem-27-4017839.0-0
- Repo with working example:
  https://github.com/TWiStErRob/repros/tree/master/kotlin/fail-on-sealed-when-info

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the recent library by JakeWharton that allows to just use `@Exhaustive` annotation.

```
sealed class RouletteColor {
  object Red : RouletteColor()
  object Black : RouletteColor()
  object Green : RouletteColor()
}

fun printColor(color: RouletteColor) {
  @Exhaustive
  when (color) {
    RouletteColor.Red -> println("red")
    RouletteColor.Black -> println("black")
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'app.cash.exhaustive:exhaustive-gradle:0.1.1'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' // or .android or .multiplatform or .js
apply plugin: 'app.cash.exhaustive'
```

Lib: https://github.com/cashapp/exhaustive

Answer (score 0):

You can override unary operator to make it less verbose:

```
operator fun Any.unaryMinus() = Unit
```

And use it like this:

```
-when (sealedClass) {
    is SealedClass.First -> doSomething()
    is SealedClass.Second -> doSomethingElse()
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642387/6528121)